# A SPARQL query to find entities that are similar to an entity

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have the URI of an entity (`:P1`) and I want to find all entities that are similar to this entity. Right now, I am trying to find those entities that are connected to `:P1` through a common entity and the same attribute. I have a query like this.

```
SELECT ?simP (SUM(?score) AS ?simScore) 
WHERE {
    {
        :P1 ?prop ?q.
        ?q ?propInv ?simP.
        ?propInv owl:inverseOf ?prop.
        FILTER(?simP != :P1).
        BIND(1 AS ?score).
    } UNION {
        :P1 ?prop1 ?q1.
        ?q1 ?prop2 ?q.
        ?q ?prop2Inv ?q2.
        ?q2 ?prop1Inv ?simP.
        ?prop1Inv owl:inverseOf ?prop1.
        ?prop2Inv owl:inverseOf ?prop2.
        FILTER(?simP != :P1).
        BIND(0.5 AS ?score).
    }
} 
GROUP BY ?simP
ORDER BY DESC(?simScore)
```

As you can see, I am trying to find those entities that are connected to P1 through a common entity at a distance of 1 hop and then 2 hops. Scores (reciprocal of the number of hops) reduce as the number of hops increase.

My issues with this query are

- It requires that each property have an inverse (`owl:inverseOf`) defined which need not always be the case.
- The number of statements in the queries go on increasing as I increase the number of hops from 1 to 2 to 3 and so on.

My question is if there is a better way to getting the outcome I am expecting. It would be great if the query can at the very least get entities that are connected to `:P1` through a common entity atleast 2 hops away without having to add the `UNION` clause for each hop.

Also, is there a better approach to getting entities considered "similar" to `:P1`.

Comment: No way afaik given that things like `:p1{2,3}` didn't make it into the final SPARQL 1.1 specs. Moreover, you assign a different score depending on the number of hops. But, I don't see a problem here, UNION is a good construct for a SPARQL engine to compute the parts it parallel

Comment: I was hoping there would some way to reduce the number of statements required as the number of hops increased. I would love it if some of the property path constructs could be applied to variables. So instead of having to explicitly mention `?propInv` `owl:inverseOf` `?prop`, we could use something like `^?prop1` or allow the use of `?prop1/?prop2` in a single SPARQL pattern.

Comment: I know all this is not possible at the moment.

Comment: It's worth noting that while "things like `:p1{2,3}`didn't make it into the final SPARQL 1.1 specs", they may be supported by some engines, such as Virtuoso, in which support for this syntax was implemented during SPARQL 1.1 development and from which this support was not removed.

Comment: @thisisshantzz the problem is, that you can't use variables in a property path. there is a workaround sometimes referred to as *"wildcard pattern"*: `(:p|!:p)`